# Conditionally add --dry-run to a publish step in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines

We have this step in our Azure Pipeline. It runs `npm run publish-shell-ui` if the branch is `main`, and otherwise step is skipped. I would like to modify this step so that the `--dry-run` option is added if the branch is something other than `main`.

```
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: "Publish"
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'))
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      customCommand: 'run publish-shell-ui'
      workingDir: '$(BuildRoot)'
```

I know I could solve this by adding a second "Dry-Run Publish" task, that would only run when the branch is not `main`, but I am asking if it's possible to make a single task, that would handle both cases because I suspect, that such a solution would be easier to read.

```yaml
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: "Dry-Run Publish"
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'))
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      customCommand: 'run publish-shell-ui --dry-run'
      workingDir: '$(BuildRoot)'
```

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi, If the answer resolved your question, you could Accept it as an Answer , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something I've used in the past are variables to store values that are changed based upon the parameters passed into the YAML pipeline/template.

I believe something like this will accomplish what you're looking for:

```
- script: |
   branch='$(Build.SourceBranch)'
   if [[ $branch == *"/main"* ]]
   then
      echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=PublishCommand]run publish-shell-ui
   else
      echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=PublishCommand]run publish-shell-ui --dry-run
   fi
  displayName: "Set Publish Command" 
  condition: ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')      
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: "Publish"
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'))
  inputs:
     command: 'custom'
     customCommand: $(PublishCommand)
     workingDir: '$(BuildRoot)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [conditional insertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion), something like this:

```yaml
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: "Publish"
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'))
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
      customCommand: 'run publish-shell-ui'
    ${{ else }}:
      customCommand: 'run publish-shell-ui --dry-run'
    workingDir: '$(BuildRoot)'
```